# MultiHeadAttention while importing tensorflow-model-optimization

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am getting following error while trying to import tensorflow-model-optimization.

```
main(args)
  File "train.py", line 284, in main
    q_aware_tflite_model = quant_aware_train(args, model, train_generator, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 133, in quant_aware_train
    import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.api import clustering
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/api/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.api import clustering
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/api/clustering/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.api.clustering import keras
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/api/clustering/keras/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.clustering.keras.cluster import cluster_scope
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/clustering/keras/cluster.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.clustering.keras import cluster_wrapper
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/clustering/keras/cluster_wrapper.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.clustering.keras import clustering_registry
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/clustering/keras/clustering_registry.py", line 57, in <module>
    class ClusteringRegistry(object):
  File "/home/tfupdated/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/clustering/keras/clustering_registry.py", line 104, in ClusteringRegistry
    tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'MultiHeadAttention'
```

I am using Ubuntu, tensorflow==2.3.0 (necessary), tensorflow-model-optimization==0.7.5 in another virtual environment as the projects needs tensorflow 2.3 for most and it creates conflict with tensorflow-model-optimization when used in the same environment.

Comment: Can you try `pip tensorflow-model-optimization==0.5.0`? It [seems to work](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9357#issuecomment-1253722888) with `tensorflow 2.3.2`.